# Edit inbound NAT pool in vmss loadbalancer

Tags: azure, azure-cli2

I'm trying to add a NAT pool for port 8172 to an existing loadbalancer via Azure cli.
I found what I believe is the correct command:

```
az network lb inbound-nat-pool update --lb-name
                                  --name
                                  --resource-group
                                  [--add]
                                  [--backend-port]
                                  [--frontend-ip-name]
                                  [--frontend-port-range-end]
                                  [--frontend-port-range-start]
                                  [--protocol {All, Tcp, Udp}]
                                  [--remove]
                                  [--set]
```

and I suppose I need to use the `--add` option.
But what's next? How do I specify the frontend and backend settings in the add command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a NAT pool for port 8172 to an existing loadbalancer
>   via Azure cli.

Unfortunately, `adding` or `editing` references between load balancers and scale set virtual machines is currently **disabled** for load balancers that contain an existing association with a scale set.

If you want to add NAT rules for VMSS, maybe we should **re-create** it.
[image]

If we use CLI 2.0 to add or update inbound rules, we will get this **error message**:

```
C:\Users>az network lb inbound-nat-rule create -g jasonvmss --lb-name jasonvmsslb --protocol TCP --frontend-port 8172 --backend-port 8172 -n nat1
Adding or updating NAT Rules when NAT pool is present on loadbalancer /subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxe29a7b15/resourceGroups/jasonvmss/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/jasonvmsslb is not supported. To modify the load balancer, pass in all NAT rules unchanged or remove the LoadBalancerInboundNatRules property from your PUT request.
```

---

**Update**:

We can use `az network lb inbound-nat-pool create` to create inbound nat pool, it works fine. command like this:

```
az network lb inbound-nat-pool create --backend-port
                                      --frontend-port-range-end
                                      --frontend-port-range-start
                                      --lb-name
                                      --name
                                      --protocol {All, Tcp, Udp}
                                      --resource-group
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized the solution is to create an additional nat-pool:

```
az network lb inbound-nat-pool create
```

Comment: Yes, we can use `az network lb inbound-nat-pool create` inbound nat pool, this command work fine, I have update my answer, please check it :)

Answer (score 0):

**First update VMSS** with ARM template by **keeping only required LB pool configuration** in networkProfile section(if the pool configuration which needs to be deleted exist, remove this. If not already exist, ignore).

After VMSS updated, review VMSS does **not** have any association with the backendpool which needs to be deleted in AzureResourceExplorer.

Once VMSS does not have associated, we can delete the address pool from portal/using ARM template

Answer (score -1):

You can actually modify Inbound NAT pools, you just have to make sure they are not in use by the VMSS when you do. I wrote a [blog post](https://ronaldwildenberg.com/azure/2018/02/09/remove-inbound-nat-rules-from-azure-vmss.html) on a related topic: removing NAT rules that were created by someone who attached a debugger to a Service Fabric cluster.

Disadvantage of this approach is possible downtime because you temporarily disconnect the VMSS and the NAT pool(s).