# Failed to update autoscale configuration. (Azure scale set)

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm receiving the following error when trying to manually increase the number of instances above 10 on an Azure Scale set.

> Failed to update autoscale configuration for 'XXXX'.{  "error": { 
>   "details": [],  "code":
>   "InboundNatPoolFrontendPortRangeSmallerThanRequestedPorts", 
>   "message": "The frontend port range for the inboundNATpool
>   /subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/LB-xxx/inboundNatPools/DebuggerListenerNatPool-4vhwwa8stp
>   is smaller than the requested number of ports 15 in VM scale set
>   /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/XXXX."
>   }  }

The default number of instances is 3 and any number up to 10 works as expected. The subscription has plenty of available cores.

Looking at the referenced load balancer in Azure portal, I cannot see any settings that are obviously linked to this error message. The LB has a setting 'SKU' that has a value of 'Basic' which i guess may be an issue? (although reading up on this would indicate the limit there is 100)

There are no google results for the code 'InboundNatPoolFrontendPortRangeSmallerThanRequestedPorts' and searching for parts of the error message didn't give any meaningful results.

Any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that if you have overprovisioning on, you will temporarily get more VMs than you asked for (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-design-overview#overprovisioning)). So you'll need to have enough NAT rules to accomidate the extra VMs. You should never need more than 2 times as many NAT rules as VMs (so if your VM max is 10, you should never need more than 20 NAT rules in the pool).

Answer (score 1):

> "InboundNatPoolFrontendPortRangeSmallerThanRequestedPorts"

This error message means, your load balancer NAT pool  is **smaller** than the requested number of ports 15 in VM scale set.

Here a example VMSS NAT pool:

```
 "variables": {
 "natStartPort": 50000,
 "natEndPort": 50119,
 "natBackendPort": 3389,}
 "inboundNatPools": [
          {
            "name": "[variables('natPoolName')]",
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[variables('frontEndIPConfigID')]"
              },
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "frontendPortRangeStart": "[variables('natStartPort')]",
              "frontendPortRangeEnd": "[variables('natEndPort')]",
              "backendPort": "[variables('natBackendPort')]"
            }
          }
        ],
```

Please check your **NAT pool range**.

About edit inbound NAT pool in VMSS loadbalancer, we can use CLI 2.0 to edit it:

```
az network lb inbound-nat-pool create --backend-port
                                      --frontend-port-range-end
                                      --frontend-port-range-start
                                      --lb-name
                                      --name
                                      --protocol {All, Tcp, Udp}
                                      --resource-group
```

Here [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646956/edit-inbound-nat-pool-in-vmss-loadbalancer/46662023#46662023) about edit VMSS NAT pool, please refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

- your IP-Address-Range in the Subnet is large enough
- you also add an "Inbound NAT rule" to the load balancer if you manually scale via PowerShell or CLI

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a load balance with an inbound NAT pool called EtwListenerNatPool-qs8az5dmgu which has a range of only 15 ports, restricting us to scaling to only 15 instances. To fix this, I ran the following commands in the Azure CLI (your name may be different, you can view the pools in the portal):

```
az login
az network lb inbound-nat-pool create --backend-port 810 --frontend-port-range-end 860 --frontend-port-range-start 810 --lb-name <lbName> --name EtwListenerNatPool-qs8az5dmgu --protocol Tcp --resource-group <resourceGroup>
```